# Invalid schema configuration: `...` is not a valid type at path `ref`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I want to use embedded populate
and keep ingredient array in recipe model
but got this error
search some sites but couldn't find answer

```
    throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}\` is not ` +
    ^

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Ingredient` is not a valid type at path `ref`.
```

here Recipe Model, I added ingredients field and give objectId type and ref but code give error in ref

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    recipeName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 2,
        max: 255,
    },
    addedUser: {
        type: {
            tpye: String,
            required: true,
            min: 2,
            max: 255,
        }

    },
    ingredients: [{
        tpye: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Ingredient'
    }]

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);
```

Ingredient Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ingredientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ingredientName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 2,
        max: 255,
    },
    quantity: {
        type: {
            tpye: Number,
            required: true,
            min: 0
        }
    },
    unit: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Unit'
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Ingredient', ingredientSchema);
```

Comment: Misspelled type in schema.

Comment: OMG how did I not see that thanks a lot @Gibbs

Comment: 3 years old, this comment saved me

Answer (score 6):

your "type" in  "ingredients:" and "addedUser:" in controller and  its writed as "tpye". try to change that!

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was `type` instead of `$type`.

whereas I have [config](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey) `{ typeKey: '$type' }`